# How long does it take to be a whitelist member?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How long does it take to be a whitelist member?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231613/how-long-does-it-take-to-be-a-whitelist-member?/) by [JeongsooLim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26550/jeongsoolim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-11**:
What do you mean exactly with 'whitelist member'?

**Comment by [JeongsooLim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26550/jeongsoolim/) on 2016-04-11**:
I want to make a document for my works.
But when I access to PackageDocumentation page, it says like below.

Hi there. In an effort to combat spam, we require that users be added to a whitelist to gain edit permissions. To gain edit permissions for yourself, please comment on this GitHub ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to make a document for my works. But when I access to PackageDocumentation page, it says like below:

> > Hi there. In an effort to combat spam, we require that users be added to a whitelist to gain edit permissions. To gain edit permissions for yourself, please comment on this GitHub ticket

The text you quote asks you to comment on [roswiki/issues/139](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/139), but you opened a [new issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/163). I think @tfoote didn't realise you want to be added to the wiki usergroup.

You can either comment on `issues/139` or add some reference to `issues/139` in the issue you opened.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2